# This app package’s publisher certificate could not be verified. App Installer Error

Tags: appinstaller

I've upload my UWP application to Microsoft Store. But when I trying to download .msixbundle file App Installer says

> This app package’s publisher certificate could not be verified. Contact your system administrator or the app developer to obtain a new app package with verified certificates. The root certificate and all immediate certificates of the signature in the app package must be verified (0x800B010A)

How can I fix this issue?

Screenshot:
[image: Error message]

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the .msixbundle package you downloaded from the submission page for installation. The uploaded project has been processed by the store， recompiled and replaced the certificate with Store-used certificate.
If you wnat to download it after published, please download it from the Store app.  If you want to sideload your app, please create sideload package instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are logged in to the store (where you uploaded your package), you select your app. Then click "manage packages" on the left side, followed by clicking "show packages" on the right. There you can download the final package as a zip container.
Inside you'll find a msixbundle file that can be installed by double-click

Comment: I can't see final zip download button. I just see "Download Windows 10/11 symbol file" link.

Comment: @MinecraftWolf, that sounds weird. That "Download Windows 10 Package" Link usually is directly above the "Download Windows 10/11 symbol file".
Are you using Edge to open that site? I had several issues with missing buttons using Firefox or Chrome.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using Microsoft Edge to open site.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. Is it possible, that your store certificate has expired and needs to be renewed?